# any function which computes list only until the value needed

Tags: python, lambda

The following code needs 27 seconds to execute on my machine.

```
any([i==0 for i in range(100000000)])
```

The reason is because python computes the whole list before it applies `any`. I want an any function which computes the list only as far as needed.

I know that you can do it this way

```
value=false
for i in range(100000000):
    if i==0:
        value=true
        break
```

But I'm looking for a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[]` to make it a generator expression, problem solved:

```
any(i == 0 for i in range(100000000))
```

For Python 2, use the generator version `xrange` instead instead of `range`.

Comment: `any(i == 0 for i in range(100000000))` still takes more than a second. And `any(i == 0 for i in range(1000000000))` takes forever.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using SageMath 8.6

Comment: I’m not sure what version of Python that is. If it’s 2.x, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: Yeah, it's using Python 2.x, see http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/faq/faq-usage.html

Comment: So, yeah, use `xrange` then.